# Проблема со шрифтом Co Headline Corp

Tags: html, css

При использовании данного шрифта через сторонние сервисы (например CDNFonts) у него есть небольшой padding-top, что доставляет неудобства. Если же скачать данный шрифт себе локально, то при небольшом размере и он начинает рябеть, размывается. Сглаживание через CSS не помогло. [image]